# Are there additional assumptions required in Chapter 20 Problem 23 of Spivak's Calculus? Using a Taylor polynomial to derive Schwarz second derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

Chapter 20 Problem 23 of Spivak's *Calculus* asks the user to prove the formula for the *Schwarz second derivative* of $f$ at $a$ using a Taylor polynomial. The prompt reads as follows:

> If $f''(a)$ exists, then \begin{align}f''(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^2} \quad \text{Hint: Use a 2nd-degree Taylor Polynomial}\end{align}

I take issue with this prompt as I believe additional assumptions are needed...namely:

1. $f'''$ exists around and including $a$
2. $f'''$ is bounded around $a$

The solution manual reads, verbatim, as:

> This follows from\begin{align} &f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2}h^2+R_{2,a}(h) \\
> &f(a-h)=f(a)-f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2}h^2+R_{2,a}(-h)\end{align} since $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R_{2,a}(h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{R_{2,a}(-h)}{h^2}=0$$

Note that throughout this chapter, Spivak almost exclusively deals with the Lagrange remainder (so the remainder, here, is likely adhering to that structure...and thus takes on the form: $\pm\frac{f'''(t)}{3!}h^3$).

Although I have some minor disagreements with the notation used in the above solution, I understand its essence and have rewritten it as:

\begin{align} &F(h)=f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2}h^2+R_{2,0,F}(h)\\
&G(h)=f(a-h)=f(a)-f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2}h^2+R_{2,0,G}(h) \implies \\
&F(h)+G(h)=f(a+h)-f(a-h)=2f(a)+f''(a)h^2+\left(R_{2,0,F}(h)+R_{2,0,G}(h)\right) \implies \\
&f''(a)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)-2f(a)-\left(R_{2,0,F}(h)+R_{2,0,G}(h)\right)}{h^2} \implies \\
&\lim_{h \to 0}f''(a)=f''(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)-2f(a)-\left(R_{2,0,F}(h)+R_{2,0,G}(h)\right)}{h^2} \implies \\
&f''(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^2}-\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R_{2,0,F}(h)}{h^2}-\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R_{2,0,G}(h)}{h^2} \implies \\
&f''(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^2}
\end{align}

In order for my argument (and therefore Spivak's) to be correct, I necessarily required that $f'''$ exists at and around $a$ and be bounded around $a$. Am I misunderstanding something here? Or has the prompt undersupplied the required assumptions?

---

**Edit:**

As *peek-a-boo* suggested, we do **not** have to interpret the remainder terms as adhering to the Lagrange structure. We can just assume that they are some unknown function that depends on $h$. Then, in order to  evaluate $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R_{2,0,G}(h)}{h^2}$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R_{2,0,F}(h)}{h^2}$ we can apply the following theorem provided earlier in the chapter:

\begin{align} &\text{Suppose $f$ is a function such that $f'(a), f''(a), \cdots, f^n(a)$ exist.}\\& \text{Then $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$} \end{align}

Applying this to our situation yields:

$$0=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)-P_{2,0,F}(h)}{(h-0)^2}=\frac{R_{2,0,F}(h)}{(h-0)^2}$$

$$0=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h)-P_{2,0,G}(h)}{(h-0)^2}=\frac{R_{2,0,G}(h)}{(h-0)^2}$$

Comment: The question is true as stated, and the hint is correct as is. You simply need to use the basic asymptotic form of the remainder (I believe it’s called the Peano form), i.e Theorem 1 of the chapter. I still don’t see what issue you have with Spivak’s solution.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ahhhh, I see. Thank you for clarifying this. I thought the structure of the remainder term was in the Lagrange form (which requires knowing the $n+1$th derivative)...but with your suggestion, I see that it's just a general remainder term (with no assumed structure) and theorem 1 can be used. Much appreciated.